# C ncurses WINDOW as extern

Tags: c, ncurses

I am writing a terminal based menu that calls a function to move up/down in the menu with the arrow keys. The problem is I need the WINDOW to be seen by two functions (neither of them is stdscr). I have tried to create an extern WINDOW by declaring it in the header with no success. Any suggestions how i can accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: Vote to close as OP solved problem by fixing typo.

Answer (score 2):

Please throw in any code you might have as well as the results and what you're running. Reading the ncurses documentation, there doesn't seem to be any real complexity here beyond a regular `extern` declaration (NOTE: Not an ncurses user or expert):

- You need an `extern WINDOW *global_win;` in the shared header.
- You need exactly one `WINDOW *global_win = NULL;` in some source file.
- You need to run `global_win = newwin();` somewhere in your initialization routines.
- After this, you should be able to call `wrefresh(global_win)` and the like from any file that includes the shared header, provided the appropriate object file is linked in (the one that has step #2).

You can also invert your model and have your libraries be functions that can operate on ANY window, e.g. `draw_circle(WINDOW *win)` - that way, your main methods include the headers from your utility modules and pass in the current working window (of which there can be one), rather than a collection of modules operating on a global shared window. This way, there's no need for an `extern` visible to everyone, but you'll have to pass the `WINDOW *` around.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I must have been starring at the screen too long today... LOL. The code to make the WINDOW extern is too easy. Just add WINDOW *win; (where *win would be the name of your window)somewhere in the header below 'include ' and then define it somewhere in any function. Sorry to be so stupid...